# Storing likes and dislikes in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Guys what is the best database model for storing user `likes` and `dislikes`?
Is good approach to have separated table like below ?:

**1.** tbl_post_likes

**2.** tbl_post_dislikes

**tbl_post_likes has:**

```
id  |  post_id<fg>  | account_id<fg> | etc...
```

**tbl_post_dislikes has:**

```
id  |  post_id<fg>  | account_id<fg> | etc...
```

Or is better to all this put in one table? But i think one table is bad approach?

I need this for my blog posts where only registred user can to like and dislike post items. If user already liked only enable dislike and the some.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Can a user both "like" and "dislike" a post? If not, the one "vote" table would be enough with a flag like/dislike

Comment: He only can like or dislike. Only have one option and only one time can like or dislike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, just need one table called

```
tbl_post_likes
```

in that table column like:

**id  |  post_id  | account_id | vote |**

in like column it`s set flag 1 or 0.

```
1 stands for like

0 stands for dislike.
```

I hope that this is good approach.

Comment: Yeah, this is okay way

Comment: if you are using more table then its not suits normalizations and your query will take more time to executle

Answer (score 2):

I would store the likes in a second table and mabye used true / false values so used a composit key for the id. Then just determine the value in the code and output the correct answer. I think it should be something like this :

```
    post_id<fg> account_id<fg> | value
```

This is done because only one user can like or dislike on post. Have a user that can dislike more than one post is stupid by my standard.